# use correlation matrix in robust PCA functions R

Tags: r, correlation, pca, covariance, robust

I want to perform robust principal component analysis (PCA) on the correlation matrix. Namely, rrcov::PcaHubert.

I know that if I give to the function cor=TRUE, rrcov:CovMcd calculates the robust covariance and correlation matrix. How can I force the PCA to use the correlation matrix instead of the covariance matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: To figure out what PcaHubert is doing with its `...` arguments, I would start by just inspecting the PcaHubert code from the command line. If what you want is possible, there must be some method called within PcaHubert that receives those `...` arguments and allows you to specify correlation instead of covariance.